# How to paste two files with different number of lines?

Tags: bash, paste

I would like to combine two files (see below) in a table format where file1 information is restricted to columns 1 and 2, and file2 information to columns 3 and 4 (tab delimited).

The problem is these files have different line numbers. This way, bash paste is not "pasting" as I have planned.
Here are the files:

File 1

```
../selected/rpoB_aln_cor_selected.fas   
754857223   Paenibacillus borealis
754847241   Paenibacillus durus
820147112   Paenibacillus durus ATCC 35681
647247545   Paenibacillus forsythiae T98
686560542   Paenibacillus graminis
AML91_04045 Paenibacillus jilunlii
740788177   Paenibacillus odorifer
515232203   Paenibacillus polymyxa ATCC 842
AMQ83_22310 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAR114
AMQ84_09005 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAS34
PRIO_6145   Paenibacillus riograndensis SBR5
644582147   Paenibacillus sabinae T27
748290938   Paenibacillus sonchi X19-5
738698737   Paenibacillus sophorae S27
655082470   Paenibacillus sp. HW567
740913783   Paenibacillus stellifer
738759525   Paenibacillus wynnii
```

File 2

```
../selected/rpsB_aln_cor_selected.fas   
738801471   Paenibacillus borealis
754845814   Paenibacillus durus
647238899   Paenibacillus durus ATCC 35681
647253447   Paenibacillus forsythiae T98
686558702   Paenibacillus graminis
AML91_12385 Paenibacillus jilunlii
738797351   Paenibacillus odorifer
503074989   Paenibacillus polymyxa ATCC 842
AMQ83_29390 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAR114
AMQ84_25055 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAS34
PRIO_4043   Paenibacillus riograndensis SBR5
644577490   Paenibacillus sabinae T27
521103275   Paenibacillus sonchi X19-5
738689566   Paenibacillus sophorae S27
518752441   Paenibacillus sp. HW567
740911441   Paenibacillus stellifer
738763159   Paenibacillus wynnii
647238899   Paenibacillus zanthoxyli JH29
```

After the command `paste file1 file2 > output`, I have the following output:

```
../selected/rpoB_aln_cor_selected.fas       ../selected/rpsB_aln_cor_selected.fas   
754857223   Paenibacillus borealis  738801471   Paenibacillus borealis
754847241   Paenibacillus durus 754845814   Paenibacillus durus
820147112   Paenibacillus durus ATCC 35681  647238899   Paenibacillus durus ATCC 35681
647247545   Paenibacillus forsythiae T98    647253447   Paenibacillus forsythiae T98
686560542   Paenibacillus graminis  686558702   Paenibacillus graminis
AML91_04045 Paenibacillus jilunlii  AML91_12385 Paenibacillus jilunlii
740788177   Paenibacillus odorifer  738797351   Paenibacillus odorifer
515232203   Paenibacillus polymyxa ATCC 842 503074989   Paenibacillus polymyxa ATCC 842
AMQ83_22310 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAR114  AMQ83_29390 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAR114
AMQ84_09005 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAS34   AMQ84_25055 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAS34
PRIO_6145   Paenibacillus riograndensis SBR5    PRIO_4043   Paenibacillus riograndensis SBR5
644582147   Paenibacillus sabinae T27   644577490   Paenibacillus sabinae T27
748290938   Paenibacillus sonchi X19-5  521103275   Paenibacillus sonchi X19-5
738698737   Paenibacillus sophorae S27  738689566   Paenibacillus sophorae S27
655082470   Paenibacillus sp. HW567 518752441   Paenibacillus sp. HW567
740913783   Paenibacillus stellifer 740911441   Paenibacillus stellifer
738759525   Paenibacillus wynnii    738763159   Paenibacillus wynnii
    647238899   Paenibacillus zanthoxyli JH29
```

In the last line, the information is dislocated one column to left.
My desirable output would be like the following one (note that the last line has two indentations at its beginning):

```
../selected/rpoB_aln_cor_selected.fas       ../selected/rpsB_aln_cor_selected.fas   
754857223   Paenibacillus borealis  738801471   Paenibacillus borealis
754847241   Paenibacillus durus 754845814   Paenibacillus durus
820147112   Paenibacillus durus ATCC 35681  647238899   Paenibacillus durus ATCC 35681
647247545   Paenibacillus forsythiae T98    647253447   Paenibacillus forsythiae T98
686560542   Paenibacillus graminis  686558702   Paenibacillus graminis
AML91_04045 Paenibacillus jilunlii  AML91_12385 Paenibacillus jilunlii
740788177   Paenibacillus odorifer  738797351   Paenibacillus odorifer
515232203   Paenibacillus polymyxa ATCC 842 503074989   Paenibacillus polymyxa ATCC 842
AMQ83_22310 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAR114  AMQ83_29390 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAR114
AMQ84_09005 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAS34   AMQ84_25055 Paenibacillus riograndensis CAS34
PRIO_6145   Paenibacillus riograndensis SBR5    PRIO_4043   Paenibacillus riograndensis SBR5
644582147   Paenibacillus sabinae T27   644577490   Paenibacillus sabinae T27
748290938   Paenibacillus sonchi X19-5  521103275   Paenibacillus sonchi X19-5
738698737   Paenibacillus sophorae S27  738689566   Paenibacillus sophorae S27
655082470   Paenibacillus sp. HW567 518752441   Paenibacillus sp. HW567
740913783   Paenibacillus stellifer 740911441   Paenibacillus stellifer
738759525   Paenibacillus wynnii    738763159   Paenibacillus wynnii
        647238899   Paenibacillus zanthoxyli JH29
```

Comment: Why would you need the last line to be intended two times? Any specific need by it? Or you want the line to be common across both?

Answer (score 0):

> In the last line, the information is dislocated one column to left.

The problem comes from the fact that the input file columns are separated by TAB, and `paste` as well separates its output columns by TAB, but only one TAB, without regarding the input structure (which is not its job, after all).

> My desirable output would be like the following one (note that the last line has two indentations at its beginning): …

A simple fix would be to process the `paste` output so that a leading TAB is doubled:

```
paste file1 file2 | sed 's/^\t/&&/' >output
```